# Transpose row to column and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
data = [[0,9], [10, 15], [11, 14],[1,3],[2,7],[4,31]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['score_x', 'score_y'])
```

I want to put both score_x and score_y into the same bins, e.g. [0,5,10,15,20,25,30]. The I need a table with rows of score_x bins and column headers of score_y bins with the count in between:

```
         score_y  0-5   5-10   10-15   15-20
score_x
0-5                     

5-10                      count...

10-15

15-20
```

I have tried

```
scores=df.groupby(bins)['score_x'].agg(['count'])
```

and get a single column with score_x grouped

And

```
scores = df.groupby(['scores_x',pd.cut(df.scores_y,bins)])
scores.size().unstack()
```

And this gives groups in column headers but I then can't use groupby again on a groupby object.

Thanks for any suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and add parameter `label` to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30]
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

df = pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df.score_x,bins, labels=labels), 
                 pd.cut(df.score_y,bins, labels=labels))
print (df)
score_y  0-5  5-10  10-15
score_x                  
0-5        1     1      0
5-10       0     0      1
10-15      0     0      1
```

If need all bins (from list) use:

```
df = df.groupby([pd.cut(df.score_x,bins, labels=labels), 
                 pd.cut(df.score_y,bins, labels=labels)]).size().unstack()
print (df)
score_y  0-5  5-10  10-15  15-20  20-25  25-30
score_x                                       
0-5        1     1      0      0      0      0
5-10       0     0      1      0      0      0
10-15      0     0      1      0      0      0
15-20      0     0      0      0      0      0
20-25      0     0      0      0      0      0
25-30      0     0      0      0      0      0
```